# Copying All Rows from child Table into Child Table whith New Id on the basis of parent Id

Tags: .net, sql, database, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Parent Table which stores the data of Employee and it's child Table Salary which Store's all the data about salary of specific Employee On the basis of EmployeeId i want to get all the Salary Rows and Insert them Again into the Salary table with different Id I cannot make the Id Auto Incremented. I need to do this with A Stored Procedure.

Thanks in Advance.

I am using Sqlserver 2008.

```
Employee Table
Id Name      Country 
1. Employee1 Pakistan
2. Employee2 India

Salary Table
Id EmployeeId Month Salary
1. 1          Jan   20000
2. 1          feb   25000
3. 1          Mar   30000
```

Now I have Employee Id 1 through which i want to get all the rows from the salary table and then Insert them again into the same salary table with New Ids.

Comment: Can you show us an example of the data, and the expected output? Do you know what the second ID is, or do you need to look it up, or do you have to use an identity lookup?

Comment: Can you show us your current stored procedure?

Comment: OK Guys can check it out Now Is that Enough or i need to do more let me know please.

Comment: Did I get this right: the `Salary.Id` column is **not an `IDENTITY` column** and you cannot make it so?

Answer (score 2):

Well, from what I understand, you should be able to do

```
DECLARE @NewID INT = 2

INSERT INTO Salary (EmployeeId,Month,Salary)
SELECT @NewID, Month, Salary
FROM Salary
WHERE EmployeeId = 1
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d254e/1)

Comment: Well I Cannot Declare @NewId like that because i dont know Exactly how many records are there with this EmployeeId in Salary table.

Comment: Your Answer is very helpful but the problem is that i dont know what to do with Id attribute of the salary table (the child table) while inserting all the rows with this employeeId. Normally i generate them from c# Code.

Comment: @khalidkhan - do you mean that your code is computing `Id` in the Salary table, rather than just marking it as `IDENTITY` and letting SQL Server generate it?

Answer (score 0):

is it the thing you want

```
DECLARE @NewID INT 

set @NewID=(select top 1 id from Employee e left join salary s on e.id=s.EmployeeId where s.id is null)
INSERT INTO Salary (EmployeeId,Month,Salary)
SELECT @NewID, Month, Salary
FROM Salary
WHERE EmployeeId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROC INSERTDETAILS1 (@EmpID int)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Sal NUMERIC(18,2)

DECLARE Sal_Cursor CURSOR -- Declare cursor

LOCAL SCROLL STATIC

FOR

Select Salary FROM EmpSal where EmpID=@EmpID

OPEN Sal_Cursor -- open the cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Sal_Cursor

   INTO @Sal

   INSERT INTO EmpSal VALUES ((SELECT TOP(1) EmpID FROM EmpSal ORDER BY EmpID DESC)+1,@Sal)


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

   FETCH NEXT FROM Sal_Cursor

   INTO @Sal

   INSERT INTO EmpSal VALUES ((SELECT TOP(1) EmpID FROM EmpSal ORDER BY EmpID DESC)+1,@Sal)

END


CLOSE Sal_Cursor -- close the cursor

DEALLOCATE Sal_Cursor -- Deallocate the cursor

END
```

Comment: Rename the tables and columns according to your design.

Comment: I have a doubt also..whether your ID column is an IDENTITY column..???which id do you mean by this NewID - ID column or EmployeeID column..??If u reply for the same i can answer it acoordingly..

Comment: Thank you so very much Rahul, Id Column is not an IDENTITY Column, And by ID Column I mean the Id Column of Salary table.

Comment: And Can i use this solution in sql server 2008

Answer (score 0):

If `Salary.Id` is not, and cannot be, an `IDENTITY` column, you could use the `ROW_NUMBER` function to assign row numbers to the subset you are copying and add those to the last `Id` value in the table to get the new `Id`s:

```
INSERT INTO Salary (Id, EmployeeId, Month, Salary)
SELECT
  Id         = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Salary) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id),
  EmployeeId = @NewEmpId,
  Month,
  Salary
FROM Salary
WHERE EmployeeId = @SrcEmpId
;
```